# I found two groups in Slackware 14, named nogroup and nobody. Why?

Tags: linux, user-groups

I wonder why in my Slackware 14 (32 bit) distribution there are two groups named "nobody" and "nogroup":

```
bash-4.2$ cat /etc/passwd | grep nobody
nobody:x:99:99:nobody:/:/bin/false
bash-4.2$ cat /etc/group | grep nobody 
nobody:x:98:nobody
bash-4.2$ cat /etc/group | grep nogroup
nogroup:x:99:
bash-4.2$ groups nobody
nobody : nogroup nobody
bash-4.2$
```

User "nobody" has "nogroup" as primary group.  So, what's the utility for "nobody" group with gid=98?
(In Debian "nobody" group doesn't exist).
Thank you